# Why do I get Request method 'POST' not supported] with Method Not Allowed, status=405 when entering users/update/{id}

Tags: java, html, spring, rest, model-view-controller

When I'm entering users/update/{id} with some id, for example id = 6, I'm getting "Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]".

Basically, what I aimed at was to when I'm going on that URL (users/update/{id}) is:

1. method updateUser() triggered by going on mentioned URL retrieves user with id = 6 from repository
2. build a viewModel from it user with id = 6
3. pass this viewModel to HTML template "registration-formUpdate" as a "user" object in `<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" th:href="@{~/registration}" th:object="${user}">`
4. which then passes this object to endpoint "/registration" and to "registrationUsersAdding()" method in RegistrationController class to automatically fill the form with values from the user retrieved from repository
5. by clicking "add" button on the "registration-formUpdate" template save the updated user to database

However, when I click the "add" buttton, I get the 405 status and "Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]"

Sorry if my explanation isn't all that good, I'm learning Spring and English isn't my first language. I've done this this way 3-4 times on different apps before and it always worked, in this same project I have Events class with different entities, but same logic and it works. I don't know why here it doesn't.

Controller class

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
public class RegistrationController {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String registrationUsersAdding(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid UserViewModel user2,
                                          BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            if (user2.getId() == null) {
                return "registration-form";
            } else {
                return "registration-formUpdate";
            }
        } else {
            if (user2.getId() == null) {
                userService.add(user2);
            } else {
                userService.update(user2);
            }
        }
        return "redirect:/login";
    }

    @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    @GetMapping("users/update/{id}")//toooooooo
    public String updateUser(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id, Model model) {
        var user = userService.userToViewModel(userRepository.getOne(id));
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "registration-formUpdate";
    }
}
```

Service class

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService implements AddUpdateGetDeleteUser {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public void add(UserViewModel userViewModel) {
        List<Role> roles;

        Role role = new Role();
        role.setType(RoleType.valueOf(userViewModel.getRoles()));// pomyslec nad tym
        roleRepository.save(role);
        roles = Collections.singletonList(role);

        User user1 = User.builder()
                .firstName(userViewModel.getFirstName())
                .lastName(userViewModel.getLastName())
                .login(userViewModel.getLogin())
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(userViewModel.getPassword()))
                .email(userViewModel.getEmail())
                .roles(roles)
                .build();
        userRepository.save(user1);
    }

    public void update(UserViewModel userDto) {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findById(userDto.getId());
        if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            User user = optionalUser.get();
            user.setId(userDto.getId());
            user.setFirstName(userDto.getFirstName());
            user.setLastName(userDto.getLastName());
            user.setRoles(Collections.singletonList(GetRole(userDto.getRoles())));
            user.setLogin(userDto.getLogin());
            user.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));
            userRepository.save(user);
        }
    }

    public UserViewModel userToViewModel(User user) {
        return UserViewModel.builder()
                .id(user.getId())
                .firstName(user.getFirstName())
                .lastName(user.getLastName())
                .roles(user.getRoles().get(0).toString())
                .login(user.getLogin())
                .email(user.getEmail())
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()))
                .build();
    }

    private Role GetRole(String roleType) {
        var role = new Role();
        role.setType(RoleType.valueOf(roleType));

        return role;
    }
}
```

Log

```
2022-12-30 00:35:43.807  INFO 5804 --- [           main] Z.Z.ZadanieRekrutacyjneApplication       : Started ZadanieRekrutacyjneApplication in 10.364 seconds (JVM running for 11.253)
2022-12-30 00:36:28.052  INFO 5804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-12-30 00:36:28.052  INFO 5804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-12-30 00:36:28.055  INFO 5804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2022-12-30 00:36:28.527  WARN 5804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [387] milliseconds.
2022-12-30 00:37:13.180  WARN 5804 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
2022-12-30 00:42:59.615  INFO 5804 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2022-12-30 00:42:59.621  INFO 5804 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-12-30 00:42:59.624  INFO 5804 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-12-30 00:42:59.646  INFO 5804 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: Could you add the package information in your snippets? Maybe your controller is not scanned by Spring?

Comment: @hiren You mean if controller is in the same package as class with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation? Controllers are in Controller package which is in Zadanie package and  class with @SpringBootApplication annotation is in that (Zadanie) package too. But I do't know if this is the problem, I can call both add and update forms but only after going from update form to add form i have this problem

Answer (score 0):

It's ok now, changed in update-form html template from  `class="form-horizontal" method="post" th:href="@{~/registration}" th:object="${user}">` to `<form action="#" method="POST" th:action="@{~/registration}" th:object="${user}">` and it works